# Laravel interface injection of decorated repositories

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've been following the really helpful [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/lessons/decorating-repositories) on decorating repositories in order to provide different layers getting data from models.

In implementing it I made 2 repositories for my `Client` model that both implement the `ClientRepository` interface (a caching repo and a db repo).

I then made a service provider and registered them accordingly.

In the same manner I did the same for an `FxRateRepository`. Here is the service provider that does the registration:

```
// Providers/DatabaseServiceProvider

public function register()
{
    // Register the fx repositories
    $this->app->singleton('\repositories\FxRateRepository', function()
    {
        return new CacheFxRateRepository(new DbFxRateRepository);
    });

    // Register the client repositories
    $this->app->singleton('\repositories\ClientRepository', function()
    {
        return new CacheClientRepository(new DbClientRepository);
    });
}
```

Now this is all well and good and works well... until I realised that my `DbClientRepository` needs an instance of `FxRateRepository`. In my service provider I "new up" an instance of each repo and pass them into the parent repos as dependencies.

Obviously I can't pass an interface into `DbClientRepository` so how do I tell Laravel to inject an implementation of `FxRateRepository` into my `DbClientRepository`?

I tried just type-hinting in the constructor of the `DbClientRepository` but I get an Exception:

```
class DbClientRepository implements ClientRepository {
  private $fxRepo;
  public function __construct(FxRateRepository $fxRepo)
  {
      $this->fxRepo = $fxRepo;
  }
}
```

> Argument 1 passed to repositories\DbClientRepository::__construct()
>   must be an instance of repositories\FxRateRepository, none given

I am probably missing out some handy feature of the IoC container but would appreciate any advice on how achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type-hinting the dependency in the constructor of `DbClientRepository` is correct, however you then can't just instantiate it by `new DbClientRepository` but have to resolve it from the IoC container with `App::make()` so Laravel can take care of DI:

```
$this->app->singleton('\repositories\ClientRepository', function()
{
    return new CacheClientRepository(App::make('repositories\DbClientRepository');
});
```

Instead of the Facade you can also just use the `$app` object:

```
$this->app->singleton('\repositories\ClientRepository', function($app)
{
    return new CacheClientRepository($app->make('repositories\DbClientRepository');
});
```